# 外回り, 内回り instead of 時計回り, 反時計回り

Tags: words

Why were the terms 外回り and 内回り chosen for the directions on Yamanote line (railway)  rather than the more straigntforward 時計回り and 反時計回り? Is it expected that people should know which matches which?

Comment: I was able to correctly guess. That maybe because the US Interstate uses equivalent terms, inner-loop and outer-loop.

Comment: Is the direction for inner and outer loops consistent across US?

Comment: Actually, the loop I rode on was called the inner/outerbelt. I was just reading the wiki on it, and apparently the inner-outer terminology is uncommon. There are [English](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inner/outer_directions) and [Japanese](http://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E5%86%85%E5%9B%9E%E3%82%8A%E3%83%BB%E5%A4%96%E5%9B%9E%E3%82%8A) entries on it.

Comment: Just a guess, maybe because they want to refer to physical track locations instead of directions. Do they use the same terms to refer to any other lines than 山の手線? If so, they can standardize the terms.

Comment: Why do you think the physical location is important than the direction?

Comment: @sawa: I'm not sure, but if I went to another line somewhere else where the directions were different per track, then I have to figure out which one is 時計回り and which is 反時計回り. Otherwise, the outside one will always be on the outside, and the same for the inside.

Comment: @Chris that makes sense. The logic here seems to be the traffic on the inside will always go clockwise (because we drive on the right), so it's easy to understand. But that logic doesn't work for Japan. Edit, actually it does make sense. I incorrectly guessed which way the Yamanote line ran.

Comment: "rather than the more straightforward"...I feel like that might be subjective, because "in vs out" seems a lot more straightforward to me than "clockwise vs counterclockwise"...

Comment: As an aside, there are alternative words 右回り for clockwise and 左回り for counterclockwise.

Comment: @TsuyoshiIto I personally always had trouble with the words you mention because, in order for that to make sense, you have to restrict yourself to the north/12 oclock position in the circle, and I do not know why. If you locate yourself at the south/6 o clock position in a circle, then rightward is counterclockwise and leftward is clockwise. Actually, by analogy from the way angles are measured in mathematics, I feel it natural to stand at the east/3 o clock position, in which case northward is counterclockwise and southward is clockwise.

Comment: @sawa: I know that the association between clockwise and 右 is kind of arbitrary.  I just wanted to remind readers of the fact that in Japanese, 右回り means clockwise and 左回り means counterclockwise, that's all.

Comment: In Nagoya on the Meijo-sen we use 右回り and 左回り instead of 外回り and 内回り.

Comment: @JesseGood Since I have trouble with those words, I do not pay attention. I rather concentrate on the nearby destinations. But I think the displays in the stations are mostly the nearby destinations. I only hear the words 右回り, 左回り in the announcements.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to what Chris said about not knowing which side ran clockwise or counter-clockwise (there might not be a train in the station, or it might have an engine on either end and be standing still), another advantage of the [concept](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inner/outer_directions#Concept) is explained on Wikipedia:

[image]
*In nations where automobiles drive on the right side of a road, traffic traveling in a clockwise direction around a loop will always be in the "inner" lane(s) (assuming that there is no lane crossing).*

[image]
*Likewise, in nations where automobiles drive on the left side of the road, traffic traveling in a clockwise direction will always be in the "outer" lane(s).*

Comment: I know that within one area where it is a custom to run on the left or the right side, the inner and outer sides will match clockwise or counter-clockwise in one way or the other, but my question is why not directly use the terms clockwise and counter-clockwise.

Comment: @sawa, I'm completely guessing here, but maybe the expressions are older than clocks. And as you know, in the southern hemisphere, sunclocks move counterclockwise =)

Comment: Surely 外回り and 内回り, which use less syllables, are easier to distinguish phonetically, less of a mouthful, and much less likely to get confused as 道路交通情報　fades in and out than 反時計周り　and 時計回り？　

Also, unless you come from a country that drives on the right and refers to the clockwise/anticlockwise lanes of its ring-roads, 外周り and 内回り are at least as easy to visualise intuitively as the "clockwise alternative"?

(I wonder the archives to the Japan Times letter pages, if they were available, would throw any light on this? :)   )

Comment: @sawa I was thinking if someone gave you directions and told you to take the 反時計周り, you would have no idea which one that was unless a train was in motion. If they said take the 内回り, you'd know to ride the the track on the inside of the bend. Of course, the station would have to have a bend or at least you would need to be able to see how the track bends into or out of the station.

Comment: @dainichi I am pretty sure that when these words came to be used for transportation systems, there already were clocks.

Comment: @Tim Your comment is convincing. It could be an answer.

Comment: @Louis I understand what you mean, but the closed ring is so huge that you cannot see which way it bends from a single perspective. Depending on the location, it could be that the local bend goes the other way than the global bend.

Comment: @sawa, I'm just saying that the direction of clock movement might not have been the most intuitive indicator available when the term was coined. In 100 years, if everybody uses digital watches, the term might again not carry much intuition.

Comment: @sawa looking on a map it's not even a ring. What do you think about the criticisms on the wiki's? I have a feeling you've formed an opinion at this point.

Comment: I still think that clockwise/counterclockwise is more natural.